# eclipse cannot run kotlin (JDK 10)

Tags: java, eclipse, kotlin, java-10

I tried to start new project in kotlin in eclipse IDE,
I install kotlin success, and with the command line I can compile and run kotlin files.

but in eclipse I have an error:

```
The archive: /Kotlin-test-4/kotlin_bin which is referenced by the
classpath, does not exist.
```

here is my error
[image: error messages]

1. I tried to set new project
2. to set the file to "kotlin file" and "kotlin class"

**eclipse**: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
**java:** java 10.0.1 2018-04-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)
**kotlin plugin version:** 0.8.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to run Kotlin with JDK 8.
1. install jdk 8.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

2. `Windows` -> `Preference` -> `Java` -> `Installed JREs` click `add`, and add `Standard VM` -> write your jdk path -> and for the `Default VM arguments` write -Xmx512m -ea -Djava.awt.headless=true -> `Finish` -> `Apply and Close`
3. right click on your kotlin project -> `Properties`  -> `Java Build Path` -> Libaries -> select `JRE System Libray` and click `Remove` ->  `Add Library` -> `JRE System Libray` -> `Execution environment` -> Select `JAVASE-1.8` -> `Finish` -> `Apply and Close`

Answer (score 0):

open Eclipse : go to `help` -> `Eclipse Marketplace` ->type Kotlin in `find` case ->  install the Kotlin plugin -> then restart Eclipse and its done.

Comment: I did it! I install the plugin but eclipse give me the error. I tried to reinstall eclipse, but nothing change

Comment: @yeo4 maybe it works with the anterior Eclipse versions I'm using `Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)` and `jre1.8.0_144`